# Setting role when creating new user with ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, roles

Setting role when creating new user with ASP.net MVC

I am looking at the default ASP.net MVC 2 controller.

How do I set the role for the new user that is created in the Register method?

Is this possible with just a simple property set or do I have to do something special?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just add the second line below into your AccountController:

```
if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
{
    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "RoleNameHere");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

EDIT: If you haven't created the Role already (you only need to do it once.), it will cause an exception.

Just put the code below above the AddUserToRole Method.

```
    if (!Roles.RoleExists("RoleNameHere"))
        Roles.CreateRole("RoleNameHere")
```

Comment: thanks for this, it helped me out. It would be good if someone could update this answer for ASP.NET MVC 4 as the accountcontroller template has changed. I put the new lines in just after the call to `WebSecurity.Login` in the Register method. Also the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method might need changing too.